# Update a row in a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

I have that table: TRANSFERS(name,surname,date0,dateF,league,team)
One player can appear more than one time. If there are a dateF null and I insert a new row with the same name and surname, I have to change dateF null previous to date0 new

How do I do that?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T1
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE on transfers
   FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 UPDATE transfers
 SET dateF=:NEW.date0 
 WHERE dateF IS NULL and name=:NEW.nameand surname=:NEW.surname;
 END T1;
 /
```

I obtained error of mutating table

I work with oracle

Comment: Why do you want to do this using a trigger?  It would normally be much better to have the piece of code that is responsible for inserting the new row take care of updating the prior row.  You could do this with three triggers and a packaged collection (or a temp table) or, depending on the Oracle version, a compound trigger with three different sections.  But that would be a lot of moving pieces to deal with and a lot of additional complexity.  Or you could remove the `dateF` column from the table and simply produce that when you query the table using a lead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do an update in a trigger against the table that it's acting on.  You could do something with pragma autonomous, but there is no rollback in the event that your initial insert or update fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an INSTEAD OF trigger and make the insert and update on your own.

Comment: INSTEAD OF is specific to updates to a view in Oracle.